# Mongoose Error: "CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value ':id' (type string) at path '_id' for model 'Post'"

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

Running into an error with Mongoose when trying to access a dynamic url from the frontend. I'm trying to create a social media app clone where you have a feed and can click on a link to then go to an individual post.

Tools used: node, express, mongodb, mongoose, react, react-router, react-query

See error message below.

**Error Message:**

`CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value ":id" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Post"`

**Frontend Link to go to individual post**

```
<Link to={`/singlepost/${post._id}`}>Link to Post</Link>
```

**Frontend Fetch: readPostRoute.js**

```
import { API_URL } from "./config"

export default () => {
  return fetch(`${API_URL}/singlepost/:id`, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  }).then((res) => res.json())
}
```

**Backend: readPostRoute.js**

```
const PostModel = require("../models/PostModel")

module.exports = async (req, res) => {
  const post = await PostModel.findById(req.params.id)
  res.json(post)
}
```

it seems as though my frontend is not able read the ":id" as an ObjectId.

This only affects the 'GET' on the dynamic URL. The 'DELETE' method using the dynamic URL works flawlessly and is set-up in the same way as the 'GET' fetch call.

Not sure what to do at this point, I've tried other solutions found here and on other forums / websites.

I've tried:

- renaming the route from '/posts/:id' to '/singlepost/:id' to see if this was the issue.
- reordering my routes in backend

Comment: figured this out. had to pass the id from the route using useParams to react query.